# CORINE Land Cover - interactive map which allows to emphasize/display/look for particular class

Tags: geospatial, land-cover

Is there an interactive map with CORINE Land Cover data, which allows to me to find places with presence of a particular CORINE Land Cover class?

Interactive maps like this one exist: https://europelandcover.ourecosystem.com/interface/ , but I'd like to see, for example, examples of occurence of "Complex cultivation patterns" (CLC242) on the map...